# Python 3.2 installation on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, failed-installation, python-3.2

I am trying to install python 3.2.3 on my ubuntu machine, which is 12.04, but I do not want to disturb the current 2.7 installation. After searching on the internet, I found a reference [here](http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-python-3-x-in-ubuntu-debian-fedora-centos/). I followed the instructions, but when trying to run

`sudo apt-get install build-essential libncursesw5-dev libreadline5-dev libssl-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev`

I get an error saying that

> E: Package 'libreadline5-dev' has no installation candidate.

What am I missing? Is there any other way to install python 3.2 on ubuntu? If I use `apt-get`, will it disturb the current installation?

Answer (score 12):

You can install as many Python versions as needed. A call to `python` from the shell will execute `python2.7` (you can check that by executing `ls -l /usr/bin/python`), python 3.2 can be called also as `python3`.

If you have even more versions, these can be accessed directly with their numbers as `python2.6` etc. I personally have versions 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 and 3.2 installed for compatibility reasons.

Comment: That is comforting to know. I will just try apt-get then. Thank you for the help.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3`

Answer (score 0):

libreadline5-dev has apparently been replaced by libreadline6. You should be able to get it just by installing libreadline-dev and letting the package manager figure it out:

```
roger@roger-HP-Z800 ~/Downloads $ sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libreadline6-dev libtinfo-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libreadline-dev libreadline6-dev libtinfo-dev
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 262 not upgraded.
Need to get 370 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,241 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
```